# Get branch name from TeamCity build

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I am deploying a nuget package which is a result of TeamCity Feature Branch build. The build number format I use includes branch name: 1.0.0.%build.counter%-%vcsroot.branch%.

I need branch name at Octopus Deploy side to customize my deploy. What is the right way to have branch name as a Variable?

Comment: You would like to get something like: 1.0.0.1-develop?

Comment: @Rob, I already have it. So my packages are named like Web.1.0.0.1-develop. What I'd like is to have "develop" as a variable in Octopus Deploy so I know which branch is being deployed (and execute deploy appropriately)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We should be able to parse this out from the Package Name and set an Octopus Variable using something like this

1. Create the variable

[image: Variable]

2. Create a step to extract the NuGet (no features) and a PowerShell step

[image: Steps]

2. Use some PowerShell to set the variable by parsing the version number of that package

[image]

Hope this helps